# PHP Mysql query to html table only inserts to first table row

Tags: php, mysql, html-table

I am trying to print all my data to an html table, which works, but only for the first table row.

My PHP code:

```
    $data = "";
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
   $data = "<tr>
                <td>" . $row['name'] . "</td>
                <td>" . $row['email'] . "</td>
                <td>" . $row['message'] . "</td>
                <td>" . $row['created'] . "</td>
            </tr>";
 }
```

My html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <th width="15%">Name</th>
        <th width="15%">Email</th>
        <th width="50%">Message</th>
        <th width="20%">Created</th>
    </tr>
    <?= $data ?>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

How can I make the table automatically insert more rows, and the MySQL data?

Both these codes are in 1 php file.

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me that you're resetting $data to the latest row for each iteration of your while loop, instead of adding new html and data to that variable. Instead use:

```
$data .= "<tr..."
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$data = "<tr>
            <td>" . $row['name'] . "</td>
            <td>" . $row['email'] . "</td>
            <td>" . $row['message'] . "</td>
            <td>" . $row['created'] . "</td>
        </tr>";
```

becomes

```
$data .= "<tr>
            <td>" . $row['name'] . "</td>
            <td>" . $row['email'] . "</td>
            <td>" . $row['message'] . "</td>
            <td>" . $row['created'] . "</td>
        </tr>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
$data = "<tr>
```

use

```
$data.= "<tr>
```

which means you are appending all the tr in the loop